# What are the advantages and disadvantages of real time collaboration in an IDE?

Tags: ide, real-time

I can think of a few disadvantages of having real time collaboration in an IDE like no two people code in the same way so there are chances of semantically conflicting edits that can break the work.

But are there any advantages to it? What are the other disadvantages?

Thank you for you answers in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real time collaboration in an IDE can be used in case of distant learning.
It can also be used to review and correct code.

The gretest disadvantage of this is that it will cause many errors when many people code together on the same document. There are chances that they use the same variables for different tasks. So, even if the program is compiled right, there are many changes of getting bugs in the code.

Answer (score 2):

There are advantages such as using it for teaching and as a code review tool.

Answer (score 1):

It also has its advantages in telephonic interviews.

Answer (score 0):

In live project we get more knowledge about requirements of the client directly,
by this interaction of user we done and deploy our project with in specified period.